# SQL Lag/Lead with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data from programmable controlers, for which I need a query.
The data is

```
Timestamp          Sensor State
2020-01-01 10:00   'S1'   'ON'
2020-01-01 10:05   'S1'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:06   'S1'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:06   'S2'   'ON'
2020-01-01 10:10   'S2'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:11   'S1'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:12   'S2'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:15   'S1'   'ON'
2020-01-01 10:18   'S1'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:19   'S1'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:19   'S2'   'OFF'
2020-01-01 10:26   'S1'   'OFF'
```

What I need, is a query which gives me a result like

```
ON                 OFF              Sensor State
2020-01-01 10:00   2020-01-01 10:05 'S1'   'ON'
2020-01-01 10:06   2020-01-01 10:10 'S1'   'ON'
2020-01-01 10:15   2020-01-01 10:18 'S1'   'ON'
```

So I need the timestamp for Switch "ON" and the first corresponding Switch "OFF"
I thought i could use the LEAD() OVER() function, but I did not manage it.
I hope you understand my problem.

Regards
Markus

Comment: "I need" isn't a question. [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: I thought it was quite well asked - he provided sample data and expected results, and clearly explained what he wanted. He did say he tried LEAD() OVER().

Comment: @JamesCasey But OP did not say *how* they used `LEAD`, we don;t have that code and we don't know what issue they had with it

Comment: You didn't need to see that code. The question contained plenty enough information to define the issue and for me to help without some incorrect code muddying the water.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the second line of your results is supposed to be S2?

You were on the right track with LEAD, this should get you there:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(
    [Timestamp] DATETIME,
    [sensor]    VARCHAR(2),
    [State]     VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO #data
VALUES
('2020-01-01 10:00', 'S1', 'ON'),
('2020-01-01 10:05', 'S1', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:06', 'S1', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:06', 'S2', 'ON'),
('2020-01-01 10:10', 'S2', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:11', 'S1', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:12', 'S2', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:15', 'S1', 'ON'),
('2020-01-01 10:18', 'S1', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:19', 'S1', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:19', 'S2', 'OFF'),
('2020-01-01 10:26', 'S1', 'OFF');

WITH d_on AS
(
    SELECT  d.sensor, d.[Timestamp] 
    FROM    #data d 
    WHERE   d.State = 'ON'
),
next_on AS
(
    SELECT  d_on.sensor,
            d_on.Timestamp,
            LEAD(d_on.Timestamp, 1, '99991231') OVER (PARTITION BY d_on.sensor ORDER BY d_on.Timestamp) AS next_on
    FROM    d_on
)
SELECT      next_on.sensor,
            next_on.Timestamp AS [ON],
            a.[OFF]
FROM        next_on
            OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT  MIN([Timestamp]) AS [OFF]
                FROM    #data d_off
                WHERE   d_off.State = 'OFF'
                        AND d_off.sensor = next_on.sensor
                        AND d_off.Timestamp BETWEEN next_on.Timestamp AND next_on.next_on
            ) a
ORDER BY    [ON];
```

Comment: an answer that begins with "I assume" ?  Should you not aske the provider of this question for more details ? Which should have been give anyway, include the details of what he tried to do....

Answer (score 0):

For your particular dataset, there are no instances where there are multiple `ON` states, so you can just use a simple `LEAD` calculation.

```sql
SELECT
  [ON] = Timestamp,
  [OFF] = NextTS,
  sensor,
  State
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      NextTS = LEAD(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor ORDER BY Timestamp)
    FROM #data
) t
WHERE State = 'ON';
```

If there could be multiple `ON` states, and you want the next `OFF` for each, you can use a *gaps-and-islands* technique:

```sql
WITH Islands AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN State = 'OFF' AND LAG(State) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor ORDER BY Timestamp) = 'OFF' THEN 1 END
    FROM #data
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor ORDER BY Timestamp ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM Islands
),
NextValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      [OFF] = MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'OFF' THEN Timestamp END) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor, GroupId)
    FROM Groupings
)
SELECT
  [ON] = Timestamp,
  [OFF],
  sensor,
  State
FROM NextValues
WHERE State = 'ON';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5425d17de1fdd1dba57fec6f11de6c7)

Answer (score 0):

I grouped the data into logical sequences to make it more robust and to handle different ways your data might be structured which includes multiple 'ON' States and cases when sensor 2 comes ON and OFF before an already ON sensor 1 goes off.

```
WITH #Grouped_data AS (
     SELECT *, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'ON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY Sensor, Timestamp) AS grouping
FROM #data
),
#Next_sensors AS (
     SELECT *,
     LEAD(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY grouping ORDER BY Timestamp) AS [OFF],
     LEAD(State) OVER (PARTITION BY grouping ORDER BY Timestamp) AS next_state
FROM #Grouped_data
)
SELECT Timestamp AS [ON], [OFF], Sensor, State
FROM #Next_sensors
WHERE State = 'ON' AND next_state = 'OFF'
ORDER BY [ON];
```

Comment: Added grouping to my previous code to ensure edge cases are handled appropriately. This should work I believe.